# PHP foreach statement within MySQL select query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

This is my data

```
id          cost    cat         foreign     colours
--------------------------------------------------------   
385_white   99      swarovski   12          black;blue
386_white   99      swarovski   12          black;blue;green
387_white   99      swarovski   12          yellow;green
389_white   99      swarovski   12          white;silver
385_white   99      swarovski   12          silver
```

This is my query

```
$checkSQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($checkSQL)) {
    echo '
        <ul class="ColourList">
            <li class="$row">$row</li>
        </ul>
    ';
}
```

Pseudo code - this should split the list into unique `li`

```
foreach ($r["colours"] as $key){
                        $key = explode(";", $r["colours"]);
                        <li class="$key"></li>
                    }
```

I want to create a list `li` item for each colour in the table row, so basically split the colon into separate rows - think it is `explode`?

Comment: You could always try it and see.

Comment: Your while loop isn't going to output correctly. since it is single-quoted.  Variables `($row)` won't be interpolated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ought to do it :)

```
$checkSQL=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($checkSQL)) {

    echo '<ul class="ColourList">';
    $cols = explode( ';', $r['colours'] );
    foreach ( $cols as $col ){
        echo '<li class="' . $col . '">' . $col . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer and glad you changed `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc`. Might want to point out the reason why you did that. Also, might want to point out that you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions at all. Aside from that, this answer is fundamentally the same as the answer that I was going to post before you beat me to it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->dbo = new mysqli(
    'localhost',
    'username',
    'password',
    'name_of_database'
);

$r = $this->dbo->query( "SELECT * FROM `products`" ) or die( $this->dbo->error );

while ( $r_items = $r->fetch_assoc() )
{
    echo '<ul class="ColourList">';
    foreach( explode(";" $r_items['colours']) as $r_color) {
        echo '<li class="' . $r_color . '">' . $r_color . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}

$this->dbo->close();
```

I have provided this code instead of the original code as someone else already provided a good example of how to fix your code to make it work. This however is an example of mysqli, you should consider using mysqli instead of regular mysql simply for security reasons... I do not know the exact reasons but I have been told its best to use mysqli instead.

please forgive me if there are any errors in my code, this has not been tested but should work.

Comment: Pretty sure it needs to be `$r[4]`, considering 0 = id, 1 = cost, 2 = cat, 3 = foreign, 4 = colour

Comment: yep, my mistake, array starts on 0 :) thanks